# Samsung Galaxy S3: cannot sign in to Play Store

Tags: google-play-store, 4.1-jelly-bean, google-account

I just got a Galaxy S3, and would like to use it as a development device.
Factory reset-ed it, and it runs 4.1.2

I successfully log in to my google account
[image]

The weird thing is every time I'm trying open Play Store, it will ask my Google account again. Weird.

One time, I got this:

[image]

I cannot install any apps from Play Store, and this is so annoying. Is there any workaround?

Comment: Are you looking for an [alternative to Google Play store](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/18806/15916)?

Comment: Well since I cannot sign in with my Google account, that means I cannot access all the Google services (mail, Play store, books, drive, etc). I restarted the phone and tried to sign several times. The same error still persists. Annoying, eh?

Hopefully Google isn't trying to make 4.1.2 obsolete...

Comment: I would flash a new 4.1.2 gapps package if you have root. Otherwise, try updating to a newer Android version via OTA (over-the-air carrier updates). I strongly suggest updating you S3 to Kitkat (4.4.x). Versions older than that are being phased out. The amount of apps you'll be able to download with 4.1.2 will be limited. For example, you won't be able to get the Chrome browser.